# How to add scroll bar just when div grows after a max-height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a cart:

```
<nav id="cart">
        <img id="cart_button" alt="cart" src="images/cart.png" />
        <div id="cart_itself">
            <img id="close_cart_button" alt="close" src="images/cancel.png" />
            <h3>Your selection</h3>
            <table>
            </table>
            <h4>Total: 0,00</h4>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The table is empty because I am adding lines to it with JavaScript (selecting the table, creating trs, tds, and appending Children. This code is not important because it is working as expected. As I click to add rows, they are being added.

This is my cart:

[image: Open empty cart]

This is my CSS code for the cart:

```
#cart_itself {
    grid-area: cart;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 12fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        "sum close"
        "text text"
        "table table"
}
```

The cart is initially display:none, when I click the button it changes to display:grid, or when I add something on the cart.

I want to prevent the cart to cover items in my page, so I set a max-height of 300px, as stated above.

Then I wanted to add scroll bars IF the content overflows, but here is my result when I start adding lines to the table:

If I turn the overflow-y property OFF, the content overflows, obviously:

[image]

Then if I turn the overflow-y property, the div collapses:

[image]

I need the div #cart_itself to grow as I continue adding new items until it reaches a maximum height (300px) and then, if more content is added, a scroll bar is included.

I've added a !important to the max-height, no success.

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Try adding height: auto

Comment: Edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.